# Set up an object so I don't have to edit it on SQL Server and VB.net project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Currently, I have the following setup for my objects to interact with `SQL Server database`.  I would like to simplify this process so that I can be more efficient with writing my project.  In Rails I am able to run a generator and it adds/edits the database, connectors, and model files. I find it is very quick and efficient process to working with my objects.  However, currently on `VB.net/ASP.net` I have the current setup for my objects.

- **XSD file**: I use DataTables here to store columns for the attributes of my objects (ex: firstname, lastname, etc.)
- **Class VB file**: I use this to store my functions for getting, retrieving, saving (etc.) my objects to and from the database.
- **SQL Server Stored Procedures**: I use this for writing up retrieves, saving, deletion methods for my objects.
- **SQL Server Tables**: I use this for storing my objects.

I would like a setup where I could save time by just editing in one place my objects and all the other being taken care of.

Is this possible?